# Confusing example of drools this operator

Tags: drools

I am learning Drools and have come across an example in PACKT "Instant Drools Starter" (page 19) that has me confused.

Can someone explain what this is actually doing please.

```
    $p : Purchase ( total > 15) 
    Purchase ( this != $p, tacoCount > 2)
```

What I understand is that the first line is finding a Purchase with a "total" of more than 15 and assigning that to a variable $p.

The second line is then (I think) saying match with another Purchase, other than the Purchase assigned to $p, with a tacoCount more than 2 .

But what purpose does that provide? What is the plain english version of these rules.

Concerned that there is something subtle hidden here or is this just a "poor" example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plain English. Let there be a purchase with a total greater than 15.- (`Purchase ( total > 15)`) and let's call it `$p`. Now, if there is another purchase (`Purchase ( this != $p,`) where the taco count is greater than two (`tacoCount > 2)`) then let's do something.

I don't think that there is much "meaning" behind this pair of patterns. I merely illustrates that you have to use the Java keyword (not a Drools operator) this to avoid the situation that the rule matches a single purchase greater than 15.- with more than two tacos. If you want two different facts, that's essential.

(It's the kind of rule some TacoHouse marketing marvel might come up with, to provide one free chili dip to a customer's next purchase, if he's had a couple of purchases like these during the last fortnight. Additional constraints may be required. -- It just might happen. ;-) )